# Passing argument in Pinia

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have Vue3 page that includes a header. The header contains user info, stored in DynamoDB in a 'student' table. One of the fields in the student data is 'school' which is a UUID. That UUID is the ID field in the 'school' table.  Along with some student fields, there are a few school fields in the header. I am using Pinia stores (both "student" and "school" stores).

I can get everything to work just fine when hard-coding the school's UUID in the API call, but I am having trouble figuring out how to actually pass the 'school' store action the UUID from the 'student' store to look up the correct school.  I have tried the solutions provided in the Pinia documentation, but it doesn't really match what I am doing. I have searched endlessly for other helpers, but haven't found anything. Any help?

Here is the student.js code:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { getStudent } from '../graphql/queries';

export const useStudentStore = defineStore("student", {
    id: 'student',
    state: () => {
        return {
            student: {},
            loading: false,
            error: null
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getStudentData() {
            const { attributes } = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            const response = await API.graphql({
                query: getStudent,
                variables: { id: attributes.sub },
            })
            try {
                const studentData = response.data.getStudent;
                this.student = studentData;
                return this.student;
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error
            } finally {
                this.loading = false
            }
        },
    },
});
```

Here is the school.js code:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { getSchool } from '../graphql/queries';
import { useStudentStore } from './student';

export const useSchoolStore = defineStore("school", {
    id: 'school',
    state: () => {
        return {
            school: {},
            loading: false,
            error: null
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getSchoolData() {
            const student = useStudentStore()
            console.log("StudentStore: ", student)    // testing the fetch from the student store
            const response = await API.graphql({
                query: getSchool,
                variables: { id: '3cca196f-cca2-48f1-a5b5-ee67ffec530a' }, // hard-coded works fine
            })
            try {
                const schoolData = response.data.getSchool;
                this.school = schoolData;
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error
            } finally {
                this.loading = false
            }
        },
    },
});
```

I only need the student.school field... not the whole student object...but haven't been able to get either of those....

Tried numerous versions of `this.student` - `studentData` - `this.studentData` - `getStudentData().student` .... and more

Comment: `const student = useStudentStore()` assigns the store object, not the piece of state 'student'.  so the school property should be on `student.student.school`.  I would probably rename the const variable to something more appropriate like `studentStore` so then the school id would be accessed with `studentStore.student.school`

Comment: @yoduh I changed the name to studentStore as you suggested, and tried the student.student.store, but it still shows as 'undefined'

Comment: When I use just 'console.log(studentStore)' it shows "Proxy {$id: 'student' .....} , so I know it is retrieving the store correctly, just can't figure out how to access the data inside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  actions: {
    async getSchoolData() {
      this.loading = true
      const std = useStudentStore()
      const id =
        std.student?.school ||
        (await std.getSchoolData().then(() => std.student?.school))
      try {
        this.school = await API.graphql({
          query: getSchool,
          variables: { id }
        }).data.getSchool
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error
      } finally {
        this.loading = false
      }
    }
  }
```

This will return `student.school` if it has already been populated, or call `getSchoolData()` (which populates and then returns it).

From what you've shown, keeping school and student data in separate stores seems wrong. I don't see a reason why they wouldn't be in the same store, especially since they're tightly coupled. But, then again, you haven't shown much of your app's business logic, so I might be wrong.

Comment: That worked beautifully...thanks!  I have them as separate stores, since the student store is only one of the entities that will need to pull data from the school store (others would be parents, teachers, etc) -- I will amend this code later for that, once I understand how to properly pass arguments from the component to the store. I have not found any documentation for what the question mark does in that setting for the const.... so I am not sure why the code works, but it does.

Comment: @dm: the `?.` is called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). As for your stores, there's no general rule, you can have one for the entire app or you can have one for every piece of state in your business logic. The tendency is to group stuff that's related into a single store, to reduce boilerplate. I would probably use a single store for everything, since it seems all related, but I can't really advise without more detail.